# Error in Active Directory: "ldap_search: "Search: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error"

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

This error happen when using ldapfilter "has value" like:

```
ldap_search($conn, "OU=Home,DC=local,DC=intra", "(&(cn=*))");
```

Filter: "**(&(cn=*))**" or "**(&**(someattr=somevalue)**(anyAttribute=*))**" or anything with **someattr=***

Exception message:

> *ldap_search(): Search: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error*

When filter is something like **(&(cn=*my*name*))** everything works fine but if some attribute in filter has only "*", it's fail.

*ldap_set_option* is

```
LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION = 3
LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS = false
```

PS:

- It's working until yesterday.
- Same error when testing using another users for bind/connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

No direct solution,

Domain Controller was with **"disk full"**!